# Java how to set objects type

Tags: java

For example I have a class which starts like this

```
public class Class<T> {
    private ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

In main when I do

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Class x = new Class();
```

All elements in x should be of Integer type. How can I do something like `Class x = new Integer/String ... Class();` So I can specify the type of the objects in x

Comment: Don't call a `class` `Class` this is just confusing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It is also not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    private final List<T> x = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Now your `List` is of the generic type given to `MyClass`.

**EDIT**

OP in comment - *if I want to make a fonction which adds elements to x.*

In order to do that you need to create a **method** (rather than function) that takes an item of type `T` and adds it to `x`

```
public void addThing(final T thing) {
    x.add(thing);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think thats what I need. But if I want to make a fonction which adds elements to x. How can I call it? x.add(T object?)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I tried to vote up but says that I need 15 reputation

Comment: One more question. Why private final List<T> x and not private final ArrayList<T> x ? What's the difference?

Comment: Because you should always [program to the interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). `List` is the interface and `ArrayList` is the implementation. You should probably read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

```
public class YourClass<T>{
    private ArrayList<T> x = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Then in Main

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        YourClass<Integer> x = new YourClass<Integer>();
}
```

or

```
YourClass<String> x = new YourClass<String>();
```

`YourClass<T>` could be then an `Integer`, `String`, or whatever.

Comment: This is what you want. +1 for saying that it's generics that the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<Integer> x = new Class<Integer>();
```

Don't use names for classes that are already defined in `java.lang` package.

Comment: OP Probably also needs to change to `private ArrayList<T> x = new ArrayList<T>();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by Polymorphism and Generics.

What you want:

```
Class x = new Integer();
```

is polymorphism. This statement will only be valid if Class is a base class of Integer, which is clearly not the case.

```
Parent x = new Child();
```

will work if

```
class Child extends Parent {
    ....
}
```

The class you have written:

```
public class Class<T> {
    private ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ....
}
```

is a generic class but you do not use the type parameter. This is not a problem though, your class will still work. When you say:

```
Class x = new Class();
```

The type T will simply be Object. But since you do not use this type parameter, it does not have any effect.

To summarize, your statement of:

```
Class x = new Integer();
```

will never work as Integer does not have a "is a" relationship with Class. Generics is not used for this purpose.

Comment: Yes. The type parameter T will be used as an actual type if you specify it. If you say Class<Integer> x = new Class<Integer>(); Then in your class, everywhere T is used, it means Integer. Check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm